# Can window-height be ignored in display-buffer-alist after initial creation?

Tags: window, display-buffer-alist

Currently I'm using the following `display-buffer-alist`,
which works fine but resets the size on opening a new window.

Is there a way to only use the `window-height` when first creating the window? After this, any resizing I do should be kept instead of being reset (when viewing another commit in this example).

```el
(push
 (list
  "\\`magit-revision: "
  (list 'display-buffer-reuse-window 'display-buffer-below-selected)
  (cons 'window-height    0.8)
  (cons 'reusable-frames 'visible))
 display-buffer-alist)
```

Comment: I don't know if there is a simple setting, but the `display-buffer-alist` accepts custom functions that can do whatever the heart desires:  `(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '("REGEXP" . (my-custom-function)))`  The custom function takes two arguments:  `BUFFER` `ALIST`.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to use this to get the desired result (posted in answer).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by wrapping `display-buffer-reuse-window' to filter out the window-height from the alist, so it's only used for other functions (in this case` display-buffer-below-selected').

```el
(defun my-display-buffer-reuse-window-without-size (buffer alist)
  "Wrap `display-buffer-reuse-window' ignoring window-height."
  (let *((skip-params (list 'window-height 'window-width 'window-min-height))
         (alist-filter
          (delete nil (mapcar (lambda (x)
                                (if (and (consp x) (memq (car x) skip-params))
                                    nil
                                  x))
                              alist))))
       (display-buffer-reuse-window buffer alist-filter)))

(push (list "\\`magit-revision: "
            (list 'my-display-buffer-reuse-window-without-height
                  'display-buffer-below-selected)
            (cons 'reusable-frames 'visible)
            (cons 'window-height 0.9))
      display-buffer-alist)
```